# How to resolve AWS S3 URL says West, Bucket says East?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

For a Rails app, after configuring Heroku and Amazon S3, I was getting the following error message when images are posted on to the platform:

[image: Error Message]

Troubleshooting, I run the Heroku tails command to see what could be the cause of the problem.

Here's the error line:

2017-10-07T05:10:23.522407+00:00 app[web.1]: Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (unable to connect to `s3.US_East.amazonaws.com`; SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):

Then, I logged in to my AWS S3 bucket, and noticed something really strange, and I believe this is the issue, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

The Amazon S3 URL in the browser says: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-west-2#

And, the bucket (I only have one bucket) says, US East.

I believe this is the reason why I'm getting the error message because the URL says "US West" and the Bucket says "US East."

[image: AWS S3]

My questions.

1 ) Is this a bug on Amazon's end, or am I missing something here?

2 ) Do you know of any ways to fix it?

Comment: Please show us the code where you are specifying the AWS region.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such S3 URL s3.US_East.amazonaws.com. This is why it is failing.

Bucket URLs follow this format: http://s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/bucket

For us-east-1 the region name is not necessary: http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket

S3 URLs are lower case. Do not use Upper or Mixed case.

[Working with Amazon S3 Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)

Comment: S3 regional endpoints do not universally support the `s3-region.amazonaws.com` URL format. The newest regions have a dot, not a dash, e.g. `s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` and the older regions now have this newer format in their SSL cert SAN as well, suggesting that AWS may eventually be officially supporting the dotted format for consistency.  Meanwhile, the authoritative list is at [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region).

Comment: Michael, you are correct. Since Luke's question was for us-east-1, I was trying to not over complicate the answer with extra details. I provided a document link so that Luke could start understanding how endpoints work. As you know, an entire book could be written about S3.

Comment: Indeed.  I suspect there's actually some code where the "region" is being set, rather than an entire URL being coded in.  It would be helpful to see that code, I suspect.

Comment: Somewhere an invalid bucket name is being specified. AWS SDKs will not generate an endpoint such as s3.US_East.amazonaws.com. In regards to dashes versus dots in endpoints, this is probably related to transitioning to S3V4 signing. Some endpoints only support the dashed format for now. The dotted format makes more sense for the future.

Comment: Would you suggest creating a new bucket, then redoing the process? (Connecting Heroku to AWS S3)

Comment: No, I would investigate what is wrong first. Debugging helps improve skill sets and code comfort. You can consider redoing everything after that step just to reinforce the correct procedures and to document everything.